# Error : Appname has stopped working

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-metro, clr

I have developed one application in 64 bit using vb.net 2010. I am using 64bit OS windows7. When I run setup of this application,it gives error as "Appname has stopped working"
In details of error window, it has showed some files as below

Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: xmlsoa.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 0.0.3.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5141c1a6
  Problem Signature 04: xmlSOA
  Problem Signature 05: 0.0.3.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5141c1a6
  Problem Signature 07: 4
  Problem Signature 08: 7
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidCastException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Please tell me solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a **[System.InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** which means that your code tries to cast something in a type that does not fit.

Try Debugging it . If you don'T have the sources perhaps try [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Also if you have ultimate edition of visual studio you could consider using [intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If i run code then it works properly.Setup is not working. then how to debug it ?

Comment: See remote debugging link. you can attach visual studio to running processes